# powershell export to csv ISSUE

Tags: powershell

I need to fetch data with the request API and export it to a CSV file,
each column will need to be the name of a group and below all the members (the group name and the members are information that I receive from the request API).

This is the code:

```
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://X.X.X.X/policy/api/v1/infra/domains/default/groups/<group-name>/members/virtual-machines' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers

    $members_of_group = $response.results

    $out_csv =@()

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $members_of_group.Length; $i++)

    {
     $members = $members_of_group[$i].display_name
     Write-Output $members
     $out_csv += $members
     $count = $i
    }
    $out_csv | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the output:
[image]

How can I export each group name with all the members?

Comment: Please show us what is in `$members_of_group`

Comment: I managed to fix it, do you have any idea how I export a new column to the same CSV file?

Comment: If you're familiar with PSCustomObjects, I would recommend to construct one with your desired output.

Comment: If `$members_of_group` is an array of objects, you can use calculated properties to extend the number of columns like `$members_of_group | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'NewColumn; Expression = { 'Something here' }}'`

Comment: `$members = $members_of_group[$i] | Select-Object -Property display_name` instead of `$members = $members_of_group[$i].display_name`.